# echo sql or display "no items"

Tags: php, sql

The following needs to be displayed:

1. Display all items of a certain fabric
2. If no fabrics are available in the sql display "no result"

The code is fully functional for the first point but does not support the second feature.
Many thanks for helping out.

```
//echo $sql;

$data = "";
$ii = 0;
$m = 0;
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ii++;
    $m++;
    if ($m == 1) $data = $data."<div class=\"page current\" id=\"gallery\">";
    elseif ($ii == 1) $data = $data."<div class=\"page\" id=\"gallery\">";

    $data = $data."<a href=\"#\" title=\"".$myrow['name']."\" class=\"show_fabric\" rel=\"".$myrow['id']."\"><img src=\"".$image_directory.$myrow['thumbnail']."\" width=\"100 px\" height=\"100 px\"><div class=\"fb_name\">".$myrow['name']."</div></a>\n";
    if ($ii == 10) {
        $data = $data."</div>";
        $ii = 0;
    }
}
    if ($ii != 10) {
        $data = $data."</div>";
    }

if (empty($data)) echo "No result";
else echo $data;
```

Comment: if you have no result and `$ii` didn't increment you seem to always do this `$data = $data."</div>";` which makes `empty($data)` return `false`

Answer (score 1):

```
    if($result && mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
    {
     $data = "";
   $ii = 0;
  $m = 0;
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $ii++;
    $m++;
    if ($m == 1) $data = $data."<div class=\"page current\" id=\"gallery\">";
    elseif ($ii == 1) $data = $data."<div class=\"page\" id=\"gallery\">";

    $data = $data."<a href=\"#\" title=\"".$myrow['name']."\" class=\"show_fabric\" rel=\"".$myrow['id']."\"><img src=\"".$image_directory.$myrow['thumbnail']."\" width=\"100 px\" height=\"100 px\"><div class=\"fb_name\">".$myrow['name']."</div></a>\n";
    if ($ii == 10) {
        $data = $data."</div>";
        $ii = 0;
    }
}
    if ($ii != 10) {
        $data = $data."</div>";
    }

    }else
    echo('No Result');
```

Comment: I'm sorry for my ignorance but I'm not a developer. How would this particular change look for the code above? I don't want to mess something up. Thank you!

Comment: I was too fast :) Unfortunately the code works if the fabric is not available but does not display the fabrics when they are available.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($result)
{
   while()
  {
   -----
   --
   -
   }
}
else
echo "No Result";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following modified code, but it still creates a new `<div [...] id="gallery">` every ten iterations. Note that HTML IDs must be unique.

```
if ( ( !$result ) || ( 0 == mysql_num_rows( $result ) ) ) {
    echo 'No result';
}
else {
    $data = "";
    $ii = 0;
    $m = 0;
    while ( $myrow = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
        $ii++;
        $m++;
        if ( $m == 1 ) {
            $data .= '<div class="page current" id="gallery">';
        }
        elseif ( $ii == 1 ) {
            $data .= '<div class="page" id="gallery">';
        }
        $data .= '<a href="#" title="' . $myrow['name'] . '" class="show_fabric" rel="' . $myrow['id'] . '"><img src="' . $image_directory . $myrow['thumbnail'] . '" width="100px" height="100px"><div class="fb_name">' . $myrow['name'] . "</div></a>\n";
        if ( $ii == 10 ) {
            $data .= "</div>";
            $ii = 0;
        }
    }
    if ( $ii != 10 ) {
        $data .= "</div>";
    }
    echo $data;
}
```